# Transmission causes all system processes using networking to freeze

Tags: torrent

When using the app [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com) for bit torrent downloads, something will happen to the network stack that causes all applications using networking to hang.  This problem will persist, it seems, until the system is rebooted.

This is a [known issue](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/1201) reported in 2008 but it has not been resolved because the developers claim that it is a problem with the operating system.  I'm running High Sierra and seeing this problem occur consistently after between 2 hours and a few days of starting Transmission.

Is there a known workaround or solution for this problem?

Comment: The known issue refers to Transmission v1.61+. What version are you using?  Current version 2.94.

Comment: @Gilby: Yeah, I'm using 2.94.  Or was, until I switched over to qBitTorrent because of this issue.